# MassTransit Kafka producers configure to send several events to the same Kafka topic

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, masstransit

I am using Masstransit library for sending data to Kafka. There is one specific case where I have to send 3 different events to the same Kafka topic. But it looks like Masstransit doesn't support it as it uses **topicName** as a **key** for Dictionary to store Kafka producers:

```
void IKafkaFactoryConfigurator.TopicProducer<TKey, TValue>(string topicName, ProducerConfig producerConfig,
    Action<IKafkaProducerConfigurator<TKey, TValue>> configure)
    where TValue : class
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topicName))
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(topicName));
    if (producerConfig == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(producerConfig));

    var added = _producers.TryAdd(topicName, topic => CreateSpecification(topic, producerConfig, configure));

    if (!added)
        throw new ConfigurationException($"A topic producer with the same key was already added: {topicName}");
}
```

Does anyone face with the issue? Maybe there are any workarounds?

Comment: The [Kafka Sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Kafka) uses AVRO with a single producer to send multiple message types using AVRO unions. This is the most common approach to sending multiple event types on a single topic from my experience.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for the answer. But maybe you understood me wrong.  I will describe my task: I have 3 events inherited from the same base class and I need to push to the same Kafka topic.
To register producer I'm using the code: 
`riderConfig.AddProducer<DeletedEvent>("curomerTopic");
riderConfig.AddProducer<CreatedEvent>("curomerTopic");`
But these code fails because of ConfigurationException because it MT uses topicName as a key for  `SingleThreadedDictionary<string, IKafkaProducerSpecification>`.
In the example you have sent - a separate even type is registered for a separate topic

Comment: Oh, I understand your question. And my answer is the only way currently to do it with MassTransit.